# System.NullPointerException: Attempt to de-reference a null object

Tags: apex, trigger, soql

> Error: Invalid Data.  Review all error messages below to correct your
>   data. Apex trigger InsertContact caused an unexpected exception,
>   contact your administrator: InsertContact: execution of AfterUpdate
>   caused by: System.DmlException: Update failed. First exception on row
>   0 with id 00190000019XMfWAAW; first error:
>   CANNOT_INSERT_UPDATE_ACTIVATE_ENTITY, InsertContact: execution of
>   AfterUpdate caused by: System.NullPointerException: Attempt to
>   de-reference a null object Trigger.InsertContact: line 43, column 1:
>   []: Trigger.InsertContact: line 43, column 1

```
if ( Trigger.isUpdate ) {
    //List<Account> acnt = new List<Account>();
    Account acc;
    for ( Account oldval : Trigger.old ) {
        if ( staticFun.runME ) {
            System.debug(+oldval.AccountNumber);
            System.debug(+oldval.Id);

            // Account ac = new Account(AccountNumberNew__c=Integer.ValueOf(oldval.AccountNumber));
            //acnt.add(ac);

            acc = [select AccountNumberNew__c from Account where Id =: oldval.Id];
            system.debug('account INFO:'+acc);
            acc.AccountNumberNew__c = Integer.ValueOf(oldval.AccountNumber);
            System.debug(acc.AccountNumberNew__c);

            //update acc;
            staticFun.runME = false;
        }
    }
    update acc;
    System.debug('AccountNumberNew Inserted successfully!');
}
```

I want to update standard AccountNumber field, while updating, old value has to be assigned to custom field `AccountNumberNew__c`. Kindly help me to resolve this.

Here I have used  `if ( staticFun.runME )` for prevent recursive trigger.

Comment: which line is line 43?

Comment: Is this still a problem? If so, what did you try yourself to fix it? If you already fixed it, please accept an answer or write one yourself and accept that.

Answer (score 1):

this is most probably happening when you try to execute this line:

```
update acc;
```

Most probably `acc` variable is still `null` at this point, which can happen because of 2 reasons:

1. Your `Trigger.old` is empty, so you never get inside the loop
2. `staticFun.runMe` is always `false`, so you never get inside this if-statement

Also, this line

```
acc = [select AccountNumberNew__c from Account where Id =: oldval.Id];
```

is a query inside the for-loop. The best practice is to move all queries outside the loops. Read about governor limits in Salesforce.

Comment: this will fail with null pointer exception as you are not instantiating the object. Since your are going to update the object with new value you need to instantiate the object. Good practice is to take the values in a List and then do a null check before doing a update.